# JSF 2.3 + Eclipse + Maven + Tomcat 8

Tags: jsf

Am new to JSF and wanted to start from scratch. Could someone help me with the required dependencies (pom.xml) and other files like the FacesConfig, beans.xml

Comment: Questions like these are off topic on SO. See [ask].

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info